# Computation performance involving multiple numeric integrals

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, programming

I have the following code that has been running for more than three days without an answer, unfortunately. Now, my institution provides us with a computer with Intel Xeon CPU E-52650 v3 @ 20 CPU, 2.3GHz and 32 GB RAM. I have tried the same code on this computer, and it is taking the same time and still running without getting any answer.

I heard that we can use `` Needs["CUDALink`"] `` but it gave us `False`. I don't know now how I can benefit from the multi-core computer to speed up our computations or even how to rewrite the code in different way to help in the process. Is there any package we have to download to benefit from the supercomputer? Also, I saw online some info regarding parallel computing but I really don't understand it. **Can any one help me speed up this computation?**

Here is the code I wrote to evaluate my desired result, `ae`:

```
psi1[x_] :=1/24 (-4 (-2 + x)^3 Sign[-2 + x] + (-3 + 2 x)^3 Sign[-(3/2) + x] - 8 Sign[-1 + x] + 24 x Sign[-1 + x] - 24 x^2 Sign[-1 + x] + 
 8 x^3 Sign[-1 + x] + 3 Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 
 18 x Sign[-(1/2) + x] + 36 x^2 Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 
 24 x^3 Sign[-(1/2) + x] + 3 Sign[1/2 + x] + 18 x Sign[1/2 + x] + 
 36 x^2 Sign[1/2 + x] + 24 x^3 Sign[1/2 + x] - 8 Sign[1 + x] - 
 24 x Sign[1 + x] - 24 x^2 Sign[1 + x] - 8 x^3 Sign[1 + x] - 
 27 Sign[3/2 + x] - 54 x Sign[3/2 + x] - 36 x^2 Sign[3/2 + x] - 
 8 x^3 Sign[3/2 + x] + 32 Sign[2 + x] + 48 x Sign[2 + x] + 
 24 x^2 Sign[2 + x] + 4 x^3 Sign[2 + x]);

psi2[x_] := 1/(4 Sqrt[
6]) (Sign[1/2 - x] + 2 (-2 + x)^3 Sign[-2 + x] + 
 27 Sign[-(3/2) + x] - 54 x Sign[-(3/2) + x] + 
 36 x^2 Sign[-(3/2) + x] - 8 x^3 Sign[-(3/2) + x] - 
 8 Sign[-1 + x] + 24 x Sign[-1 + x] - 24 x^2 Sign[-1 + x] + 
 8 x^3 Sign[-1 + x] + 6 x Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 
 12 x^2 Sign[-(1/2) + x] + 8 x^3 Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 
 20 x^3 Sign[x] + Sign[1/2 + x] + 6 x Sign[1/2 + x] + 
 12 x^2 Sign[1/2 + x] + 8 x^3 Sign[1/2 + x] + 8 Sign[1 + x] + 
 24 x Sign[1 + x] + 24 x^2 Sign[1 + x] + 8 x^3 Sign[1 + x] - 
 27 Sign[3/2 + x] - 54 x Sign[3/2 + x] - 36 x^2 Sign[3/2 + x] - 
 8 x^3 Sign[3/2 + x] + 16 Sign[2 + x] + 24 x Sign[2 + x] + 
 12 x^2 Sign[2 + x] + 2 x^3 Sign[2 + x]);

psi3[x_] :=1/24 (-4 (-2 + x)^3 Sign[-2 + x] + 
 3 (-3 + 2 x)^3 Sign[-(3/2) + x] + 56 Sign[-1 + x] - 
 168 x Sign[-1 + x] + 168 x^2 Sign[-1 + x] - 
 56 x^3 Sign[-1 + x] - 7 Sign[-(1/2) + x] + 
 42 x Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 84 x^2 Sign[-(1/2) + x] + 
 56 x^3 Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 7 Sign[1/2 + x] - 42 x Sign[1/2 + x] - 
 84 x^2 Sign[1/2 + x] - 56 x^3 Sign[1/2 + x] + 56 Sign[1 + x] + 
 168 x Sign[1 + x] + 168 x^2 Sign[1 + x] + 56 x^3 Sign[1 + x] - 
 81 Sign[3/2 + x] - 162 x Sign[3/2 + x] - 108 x^2 Sign[3/2 + x] - 
 24 x^3 Sign[3/2 + x] + 32 Sign[2 + x] + 48 x Sign[2 + x] + 
 24 x^2 Sign[2 + x] + 4 x^3 Sign[2 + x]);

psi4[x_] :=1/12 (-(-2 + x)^3 Sign[-2 + x] + (-3 + 2 x)^3 Sign[-(3/2) + x] + 
 28 Sign[-1 + x] - 84 x Sign[-1 + x] + 84 x^2 Sign[-1 + x] - 
 28 x^3 Sign[-1 + x] - 7 Sign[-(1/2) + x] + 
 42 x Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 84 x^2 Sign[-(1/2) + x] + 
 56 x^3 Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 70 x^3 Sign[x] + 7 Sign[1/2 + x] + 
 42 x Sign[1/2 + x] + 84 x^2 Sign[1/2 + x] + 
 56 x^3 Sign[1/2 + x] - 28 Sign[1 + x] - 84 x Sign[1 + x] - 
 84 x^2 Sign[1 + x] - 28 x^3 Sign[1 + x] + 27 Sign[3/2 + x] + 
 54 x Sign[3/2 + x] + 36 x^2 Sign[3/2 + x] + 
 8 x^3 Sign[3/2 + x] - 8 Sign[2 + x] - 12 x Sign[2 + x] - 
 6 x^2 Sign[2 + x] - x^3 Sign[2 + x]);

psi1jk[x_, j_, k_] :=Piecewise[{{(Sqrt[2])^j psi1[2^j x - k], 
 0 <= j}, {2^j psi1[2^j (x - k)], j < 0}}];
psi2jk[x_, j_, k_] :=Piecewise[{{(Sqrt[2])^j psi2[2^j x - k], 
 0 <= j}, {2^j psi2[2^j (x - k)], j < 0}}];

psi3jk[x_, j_, k_] :=Piecewise[{{(Sqrt[2])^j psi3[2^j x - k], 
 0 <= j}, {2^j psi3[2^j (x - k)], j < 0}}];

psi4jk[x_, j_, k_] :=Piecewise[{{(Sqrt[2])^j psi4[2^j x - k], 
 0 <= j}, {2^j psi4[2^j (x - k)], j < 0}}];

PSI[j_, k_, l_, s_] :=NIntegrate[
 psi1jk[x, j, 
   k]*(psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + psi3jk[x, l, s] + 
    psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x, -1, 1}] - 
NIntegrate[(x t + (x t)^2)*
  psi1jk[t, j, 
   k]*(psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + psi3jk[x, l, s] + 
    psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x, -1, 1}, {t, -1, 1}] + 
NIntegrate[
 psi2jk[x, j, 
   k]*(psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + psi3jk[x, l, s] + 
    psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x, -1, 1}] - 
NIntegrate[(x t + (x t)^2)*
  psi2jk[t, j, 
   k]*(psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + psi3jk[x, l, s] + 
    psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x, -1, 1}, {t, -1, 1}] + 
NIntegrate[
 psi3jk[x, j, 
   k]*(psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + psi3jk[x, l, s] + 
    psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x, -1, 1}] - 
NIntegrate[(x t + (x t)^2)*
  psi3jk[t, j, 
   k]*(psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + psi3jk[x, l, s] + 
    psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x, -1, 1}, {t, -1, 1}] + 
NIntegrate[
 psi4jk[x, j, 
   k]*(psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + psi3jk[x, l, s] + 
    psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x, -1, 1}] - 
NIntegrate[(x t + (x t)^2)*
  psi4jk[t, j, 
   k]*(psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + psi3jk[x, l, s] + 
    psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x, -1, 1}, {t, -1, 1}];

ce = ArrayReshape[Table[PSI[j, k, l, s], {j, -4., 4.}, {k, -32., 17.}, {l, -4.,4.}, {s, -32., 17.}], {450, 450}];

coef = Flatten[Table[NIntegrate[(psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + 
   psi3jk[x, l, s] + psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x, -1, 1}], {l, -4.,4.}, {s, -32., 17.}]];

ae = PseudoInverse[ce].coef
```

Your support is much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you'd like to say some words about what you are doing there? Are all those `Sign`s really necessary? Why do all the `Sign`s pop up? Are they necessary? They might be a major obstruction for using more efficient integration schemes. Does the matrix `ce` in the end happen to contain many zeroes? Then most of the  integrals are superfluous.

Comment: And forget about Cuda for the moment. This code won't run on a GPU without major refactorization.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I am working on some simulation that used wavelets generated by B-splines. `Sign` functions there after I did the Fourier transform to get the form of B-splines in time domain. We can't remove all of them as it is essential to get the domain of each spline. What do you mean for using efficient integration schemes?

Comment: Btw.: A 20 core machine is not a "supercomputer" nowerdays. And your code employs no parallelization, so it runs only on one core at the moment. I guess you can get rid of almost all integrations but I don't see any meaning in the integrals. This looks a bit as if wavelets were involved...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The matrix `ce` yes has many zeros and may have multiple rows with a zero values, but I cant ignore them as I have rows after them that are not zero. If we skip them we will get bad approximation. So I don't know if there is a way to skip them and consider those nonzero without affecting evaluating the vector `ae`.

Comment: Can you predict where the non-zero entries in the matrix will appear? Then you only have to compute those and store them in a `SparseArray`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yes I can predict them, but again predicting them require the evaluations of `PSI[j,k,l,s]` in order to get those j,k,l,s that make `PSI[j,k,l,s]` nonzero. Also, storing them will not change the size but yes may reduce calculating those zero entries

Comment: @Mutaz I think you misunderstand Henrik's comment. What he means is, do you know of specific conditions between j, k, l, s that will cause `PSI[j, k, l, s]` to be necessarily equal to zero? For instance, some symmetry inherent to the underlying problem or some other such relationship? *Most* of the entries in `ce` seem to be zero, at least after calculating a few hundred of them, so if you could *predict* which ones are zero, and *only calculate the others*, this would go a VERY long way towards speeding up your calculation.

Comment: @MarcoB In fact not most of `ce` will be zeros. I have been calculating it for different systems, however, most of them are not zeros. I think i can't predict them without calculating `PSI`. What I just did is the following `g[j_, k_, l_, s_] := If[PSI[j, k, l, s] != 0 , {j, k, l, s}, "x"];
Table[g[j, k, l, s], {j, -1, 1}, {k, -20, 7}, {l, -1, 1}, {s, -20, 7}]`  and seems  I will not get the answer in a short time.

Comment: I would minimize NIntegrate operations: `PSI[j_, k_, l_, s_] :=NIntegrate[(psi1jk[x, j, k] + psi2jk[x, j, k] + psi3jk[x, j, k] + psi4jk[x, j, k])*
     (psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + psi3jk[x, l, s] + psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x, -1, 1}]      - 
   NIntegrate[(x*t + (x*t)^2)*(psi1jk[t, j, k] + psi2jk[t, j, k] + psi3jk[t, j, k] + psi4jk[t, j, k])*
     (psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + psi3jk[x, l, s] + psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x, -1, 1}, {t, -1, 1}]`

Comment: Then `AbsoluteTiming[
 res = ParallelTable[
    PSI[j, k, l, s], {j, -1, 1}, {k, -1, 1}, {l, -1, 1}, {s, -1, 1}];]` needs about 20 seconds on a 4-core machine.So depending on possible numerical integration issues your 400000 numerical integrations should run in a night on your 20-core machine. BTW: I tried to use Compile, but it does not speed up much.

Comment: @RolfMertig I dont have a probelm with this short values of j,k,l,s you have chose. But when it comes to `{j, -4., 4.}, {k, -32., 17.}, {l, -4.,4.}, {s, -32., 17.}` we will get stuck. Agree?

Comment: No, not in principle. Just run it.

Comment: @RolfMertig I am using now your suggestion and started evaluating `PSI[j,k,l,s]` and it still running since your post.

Comment: PSI[0, 0, 0, 0] gives 0.28552 for me. For you too?

Comment: Yes it is, It gave me `0.2855201413961725` as I am using 16 digits.

Answer (score 3):

Start with a simpler problem. I you change the iterators below (after `With`[ )  gradually you will get an idea how the complexity of your problem behaves. If there are no surprises with NIntegrate your 405000 calls to NIntegrate should be doable on your multicore machine during a night or so.

```
    psi1[x_] := (1/24)*(-4*(-2 + x)^3*Sign[-2 + x] + (-3 + 2*x)^3*Sign[-(3/2) + x] - 8*Sign[-1 + x] + 
         24*x*Sign[-1 + x] - 24*x^2*Sign[-1 + x] + 8*x^3*Sign[-1 + x] + 3*Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 
         18*x*Sign[-(1/2) + x] + 36*x^2*Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 24*x^3*Sign[-(1/2) + x] + 3*Sign[1/2 + x] + 
         18*x*Sign[1/2 + x] + 36*x^2*Sign[1/2 + x] + 24*x^3*Sign[1/2 + x] - 8*Sign[1 + x] - 24*x*Sign[1 + x] - 
         24*x^2*Sign[1 + x] - 8*x^3*Sign[1 + x] - 27*Sign[3/2 + x] - 54*x*Sign[3/2 + x] - 36*x^2*Sign[3/2 + x] - 
         8*x^3*Sign[3/2 + x] + 32*Sign[2 + x] + 48*x*Sign[2 + x] + 24*x^2*Sign[2 + x] + 4*x^3*Sign[2 + x]); 
    psi2[x_] := (1*(Sign[1/2 - x] + 2*(-2 + x)^3*Sign[-2 + x] + 27*Sign[-(3/2) + x] - 54*x*Sign[-(3/2) + x] + 
          36*x^2*Sign[-(3/2) + x] - 8*x^3*Sign[-(3/2) + x] - 8*Sign[-1 + x] + 24*x*Sign[-1 + x] - 
          24*x^2*Sign[-1 + x] + 8*x^3*Sign[-1 + x] + 6*x*Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 12*x^2*Sign[-(1/2) + x] + 
          8*x^3*Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 20*x^3*Sign[x] + Sign[1/2 + x] + 6*x*Sign[1/2 + x] + 12*x^2*Sign[1/2 + x] + 
          8*x^3*Sign[1/2 + x] + 8*Sign[1 + x] + 24*x*Sign[1 + x] + 24*x^2*Sign[1 + x] + 8*x^3*Sign[1 + x] - 
          27*Sign[3/2 + x] - 54*x*Sign[3/2 + x] - 36*x^2*Sign[3/2 + x] - 8*x^3*Sign[3/2 + x] + 16*Sign[2 + x] + 
          24*x*Sign[2 + x] + 12*x^2*Sign[2 + x] + 2*x^3*Sign[2 + x]))/(4*Sqrt[6]); 
    psi3[x_] := (1*(-4*(-2 + x)^3*Sign[-2 + x] + 3*(-3 + 2*x)^3*Sign[-(3/2) + x] + 56*Sign[-1 + x] - 
          168*x*Sign[-1 + x] + 168*x^2*Sign[-1 + x] - 56*x^3*Sign[-1 + x] - 7*Sign[-(1/2) + x] + 
          42*x*Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 84*x^2*Sign[-(1/2) + x] + 56*x^3*Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 7*Sign[1/2 + x] - 
          42*x*Sign[1/2 + x] - 84*x^2*Sign[1/2 + x] - 56*x^3*Sign[1/2 + x] + 56*Sign[1 + x] + 168*x*Sign[1 + x] + 
          168*x^2*Sign[1 + x] + 56*x^3*Sign[1 + x] - 81*Sign[3/2 + x] - 162*x*Sign[3/2 + x] - 
          108*x^2*Sign[3/2 + x] - 24*x^3*Sign[3/2 + x] + 32*Sign[2 + x] + 48*x*Sign[2 + x] + 24*x^2*Sign[2 + x] + 
          4*x^3*Sign[2 + x]))/24; 
    psi4[x_] := (1*(-((-2 + x)^3*Sign[-2 + x]) + (-3 + 2*x)^3*Sign[-(3/2) + x] + 28*Sign[-1 + x] - 
          84*x*Sign[-1 + x] + 84*x^2*Sign[-1 + x] - 28*x^3*Sign[-1 + x] - 7*Sign[-(1/2) + x] + 
          42*x*Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 84*x^2*Sign[-(1/2) + x] + 56*x^3*Sign[-(1/2) + x] - 70*x^3*Sign[x] + 
          7*Sign[1/2 + x] + 42*x*Sign[1/2 + x] + 84*x^2*Sign[1/2 + x] + 56*x^3*Sign[1/2 + x] - 28*Sign[1 + x] - 
          84*x*Sign[1 + x] - 84*x^2*Sign[1 + x] - 28*x^3*Sign[1 + x] + 27*Sign[3/2 + x] + 54*x*Sign[3/2 + x] + 
          36*x^2*Sign[3/2 + x] + 8*x^3*Sign[3/2 + x] - 8*Sign[2 + x] - 12*x*Sign[2 + x] - 6*x^2*Sign[2 + x] - 
          x^3*Sign[2 + x]))/12; 
    psi1jk[x_, j_, k_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[2]^j*psi1[2^j*x - k], 0 <= j}, {2^j*psi1[2^j*(x - k)], j < 0}}]; 
    psi2jk[x_, j_, k_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[2]^j*psi2[2^j*x - k], 0 <= j}, {2^j*psi2[2^j*(x - k)], j < 0}}]; 
    psi3jk[x_, j_, k_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[2]^j*psi3[2^j*x - k], 0 <= j}, {2^j*psi3[2^j*(x - k)], j < 0}}]; 
    psi4jk[x_, j_, k_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[2]^j*psi4[2^j*x - k], 0 <= j}, {2^j*psi4[2^j*(x - k)], j < 0}}]; 
    PSI[j_, k_, l_, s_] :=NIntegrate[(psi1jk[x, j, k] + psi2jk[x, j, k] + psi3jk[x, j, k] + psi4jk[x, j, k])*
         (psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + psi3jk[x, l, s] + psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x, -1, 1}]      - 
       NIntegrate[(x*t + (x*t)^2)*(psi1jk[t, j, k] + psi2jk[t, j, k] + psi3jk[t, j, k] + psi4jk[t, j, k])*
         (psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + psi3jk[x, l, s] + psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x, -1, 1}, {t, -1, 1}]

    With[{
    jj = {j, -1, 1}
    , 
    kk = {k, -1, 1}
    , 
    ll = {l, -1, 1}
    , 
    ss = {s, -1, 1}
    }, 
       tot = Length[Range @@ Rest[jj]]*Length[Range @@ Rest[kk]]*
            Length[Range @@ Rest[ll]]*Length[Range @@ Rest[ss]]; 
        If[Length[Kernels[]] === 0, LaunchKernels[]]; 
        klist = ConstantArray[0, Length[Kernels[]]]; SetSharedVariable[klist]; 
        SetAttributes[parProgress, HoldFirst]; 
        parProgress[ke_, n_] := 
          Row[{ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[Total[ke]], {0, n}], " ", 
              Dynamic[Round[100*(Total[ke]/n)]], " %"}]; 
        Print[parProgress[klist, tot]]; 
 (* Returning the total wall-clock time needed: *)
 AbsoluteTiming[
          ce = (ArrayReshape[#1, {Sqrt[tot], Sqrt[tot]}] & )[
                ParallelTable[klist[[$KernelID]]++; PSI[j, k, l, s], 
                  jj, kk, ll, ss]
]; 
]]
```

Comment: BTW: parProgress is a really nice utility function to monitor parallel progress and I really think WRI should build something like this into the next version.

Comment: Thank you for your email. I run your code and I got `Out[1113]= {5.84482, Null}`. What is that mean? How this will benefit me to get the vector ae? BTW I was nit able to get ride of these surprises came from NIntegrate

Comment: I put a comment into the code before AbsoluteTiming. I am afraid you have to study my code a bit by yourself and try to understand it. And then go on by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you simplify the integrals to

```
PSI[j_, k_, l_, s_] :=
    NIntegrate[(psi1jk[x, j, k] + psi2jk[x, j, k] + psi3jk[x, j, k] + 
        psi4jk[x, j, k])*(psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + 
        psi3jk[x, l, s] + psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x,-1,1}] - 
    NIntegrate[(x t + (x t)^2)*(psi1jk[t, j, k] + psi2jk[t, j, k] + 
        psi3jk[t, j, k] + psi4jk[t, j, k])*(psi1jk[x, l, s] + 
        psi2jk[x, l, s] + psi3jk[x, l, s] + psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x,-1,1}, {t,-1,1}]
```

you see that they are symmetric under exchange of (j,k) with (l,s). So if you define

```
PSI[j_, k_, l_, s_] := PSI[j,k,l,s] = PSI[l,s,j,k] =
    NIntegrate[(psi1jk[x, j, k] + psi2jk[x, j, k] + psi3jk[x, j, k] + 
        psi4jk[x, j, k])*(psi1jk[x, l, s] + psi2jk[x, l, s] + 
        psi3jk[x, l, s] + psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x,-1,1}] - 
    NIntegrate[(x t + (x t)^2)*(psi1jk[t, j, k] + psi2jk[t, j, k] + 
        psi3jk[t, j, k] + psi4jk[t, j, k])*(psi1jk[x, l, s] + 
        psi2jk[x, l, s] + psi3jk[x, l, s] + psi4jk[x, l, s]), {x,-1,1}, {t,-1,1}]
```

you save at least a factor of 2, and I'd think the code runs within a few hours on my laptop.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you may gain some speed if you simplify the psi functions like this:

```
psi1[x_] = Piecewise[{{(2 + x)^3/3, -2 < x < -3/2},
    {(5 - 2*x*(3 + 2*x*(3 + x)))/12, -3/2 < x < -1},
    {-1/4 - (x*(5 + 2*x*(3 + x)))/2, -1 < x < -1/2},
    {x*(-1 + x^2), -1/2 < x < 0 || 0 < x < 1/2},
    {1/4 - (x*(5 + 2*(-3 + x)*x))/2, 1/2 < x < 1},
    {-5/12 - (x*(3 + 2*(-3 + x)*x))/6, 1 < x < 3/2},
    {(-2 + x)^3/3, 3/2 < x < 2}}, 0]
psi2[x_] = Piecewise[{{(2 + x)^3/Sqrt[6], -2 < x < -3/2},
    {(-11 - 6*x*(5 + x*(4 + x)))/(2*Sqrt[6]), -3/2 < x < -1},
    {(-3 - 6*x + 2*x^3)/(2*Sqrt[6]), -1 < x < -1/2},
    {((1 + x)*(-1 + x + 5*x^2))/Sqrt[6], -1/2 < x < 0},
    {(-1 + (6 - 5*x)*x^2)/Sqrt[6], 0 < x < 1/2},
    {-(3 - 6*x + 2*x^3)/(2*Sqrt[6]), 1/2 < x < 1},
    {(-11 + 6*x*(5 + (-4 + x)*x))/(2*Sqrt[6]), 1 < x < 3/2},
    {-((-2 + x)^3/Sqrt[6]), 3/2 < x < 2}}, 0]
psi3[x_] = Piecewise[{{(2 + x)^3/3, -2 < x < -3/2},
    {-49/12 - (x*(57 + 2*x*(21 + 5*x)))/6, -3/2 < x < -1},
    {7/12 + (9*x)/2 + 7*x^2 + 3*x^3, -1 < x < -1/2},
    {x - (5*x^3)/3, -1/2 < x < 0 || 0 < x < 1/2},
    {-7/12 + (9*x)/2 - 7*x^2 + 3*x^3, 1/2 < x < 1},
    {49/12 - (x*(57 + 2*x*(-21 + 5*x)))/6, 1 < x < 3/2},
    {(-2 + x)^3/3, 3/2 < x < 2}}, 0]
psi4[x_] = Piecewise[{{-(2 + x)^3/6, -2 < x < -3/2},
    {((1 + x)*(19 + x*(23 + 7*x)))/6, -3/2 < x < -1},
    {-((1 + x)*(3 + x*(11 + 7*x)))/2, -1 < x < -1/2},
    {-1/3 + (5*x^2*(6 + 7*x))/6, -1/2 < x < 0},
    {-1/3 + (5*(6 - 7*x)*x^2)/6, 0 < x < 1/2},
    {((-1 + x)*(3 + x*(-11 + 7*x)))/2, 1/2 < x < 1},
    {-((-1 + x)*(19 + x*(-23 + 7*x)))/6, 1 < x < 3/2},
    {(-2 + x)^3/6, 3/2 < x < 2}}, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you for the note. Could please tell me how did you get ride of the `sign` function? What command you have used?

Comment: following Akku14's answer: `psi1a[x_] = FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[psi1[x], Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]]`

Comment: Dear friend, do you know where I can find Mr. Akku14 comments? I suddenly couldnt find it. I think he suggested a nice comments like all of you but it is nit there? Please can you help me how I can get his comments.

Comment: Maybe s/he deleted it?

Comment: I hope not, but it seems you alright 

Comment: Could you please put your code on how you got ride of the sgn function.

Comment: Could you please put your code on how you got ride of the `Sign` function. I am trying to use for many functions of the same type and have lots of `Sign`  function that I could t get ride of it. Thank you in advance!